# Is there a function similar to whenNumberLessThan but for formulas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to build a macro that will apply conditional formatting based on the value of a different cell. It's possible to do manually but entering a function, but I can't figure it out with Google Apps Script. The code I have is this:

```
conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, 
  SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1, 12)])
    .whenNumberGreaterThan('=' + spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2))
    .setBackground('f4c7c3')
    .build());
```

It fails at the `whenNumberGreaterThan` line, because it's expecting just a number, not a string as I'm providing it (i.e. a function).

And from the Google Sheets UI I can create the function easily as seen here: [image: Google sheets UI showing the conditional formatting based off a function]

Comment: Tried `.getA1Notation()`?

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing:

```
conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, 
  SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1, 12)])
    .whenNumberGreaterThan(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).getValue())
    .setBackground('f4c7c3')
    .build());
```

Comment: I did try that, and it then makes the conditional formatting based off the number in that cell at that specific time. If the number in the cell changes then I would have to remake the formatting

Comment: Perhaps if you can share an image of you sheet and explain  what you are trying to achieve we might be able to help you better.